# .removeClass() on change for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am applying these classes If the drop-down is getting selected.

```
if(elem_to_disable.parent().prop('tagName') != 'SELECT')
    {
     //alert("its not a dropdown!");
     elem_to_disable.prop("disabled", true)
     .prop("checked", false)
     .addClass("a")
     .closest(".b")
     .prepend("<div class='c'/>");       
   }
   else
   {
    //alert("it is a dropdown");
    elem_to_disable.prop("disabled", true)
    .prop("checked", false)
    .addClass("a")
    .closest(".b")
  //.prepend("<div class='c'/>");
}
```

Now on change, I want to remove all these classes for the dropdown options, i.e. the classes which are getting applied for else, remove those classes on change.

How do I go about it, Please help..

Comment: Could you update your code in fiddle.

Comment: whats issue in using removeClass()..jsfiddle plzz

Answer (score 0):

You can removeClass before adding a new class:

```
$('.a').removeClass('a');//remove from existing
elem_to_disable.prop("disabled", true)
 .prop("checked", false)
 .addClass("a")
 .closest(".b")
 .prepend("<div class='c'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
elem_to_disable.removeAttr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this..

$("#your_controlID").change(function() {

```
if ($('#your_controlID').hasClass("a")) {
$('#your_controlID').removeClass("a");
}
```

});